# how to create a list of new objects in python

Tags: python, oop, memory, reference

I am trying to create a list of new objects in python (as in separate memory locations, not references)

```
class example:
    _name = ""
    _words = []
    def __init__(self,name):
        _name = name

    def add_words(self,new_words):
        for i in new_words:
            self._words.append(i)

examples = [example("example_1"),example("example_2"),example("example_3")]
examples[0].add_words(["test1","test2"])

print(examples[2]._words)
```

`print(examples[2]._words)` outputs `["test1","test2"]`
I expected `[]` as I only added words to `examples[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_words = []` at the top of the class makes `_words` a *class* variable, not an *instance* one. All classes instances share `_words` with how you have it now.

Make it an instance variable instead:

```
class example:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self._words = []

    . . .
```

You'll likely want to fix `_name` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```py
class example:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._words = []
        self._name = name

    def add_words(self, new_words):
        for i in new_words:
            self._words.append(i)


examples = [example("example_1"), example("example_2"), example("example_3")]
examples[0].add_words(["test1", "test2"])

print(examples[2]._words)
```